# Como reiniciar um aplicação Spring Boot por código?

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber se é possível reiniciar uma aplicação Java feita com Spring Boot.

Meu Application está assim:

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Eu preciso chamar um método que consiga derrubar a aplicação e iniciar novamente, já pesquisei bastante mas não encontrei nenhuma solução, alguém sabe se é possível ?

Comment: *"já pesquisei bastante mas não encontrei nenhuma solução"* no google tem minhares de resultados sobre isso, nada disso funciona? [Restart java application](https://www.google.com/search?q=restart+java+application+by+code)  de qualquer forma, adicione na pergunta o que já tentou e pq não funcionou, e tbm o sistema operacional, pode ser que haja alguma solução mais específica/diferente

Comment: Essa classe `SpringApplication` é do Spring? Se for, já tem extensa documentação e exemplos pela Internet. Sugiro começar [por aqui](https://www.google.com/search?q=SpringApplication+restart)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Não é possível reiniciar uma aplicação **Java** por código de forma direta. O método **main** é o ponto de entrada da aplicação e é chamado apenas uma vez quando a aplicação é iniciada. Uma opção seria criar uma nova instância da classe **Application** e chamar o método main nessa nova instância, mas isso não iria reiniciar a aplicação, apenas iniciar uma nova instância da mesma.

Uma alternativa seria criar uma nova **thread** para executar a aplicação em paralelo enquanto a atual é encerrada. No entanto, essa abordagem pode ter várias implicações e depende do contexto e da arquitetura da sua aplicação. Além disso, é importante levar em consideração que essa abordagem pode ter impactos na performance e na estabilidade da aplicação.

Antes de considerar essa abordagem, seria importante avaliar se existem outras soluções que possam atender às suas necessidades sem precisar reiniciar a aplicação. Por exemplo, talvez seja possível recarregar algumas configurações ou recriar alguns objetos da aplicação sem precisar reiniciá-la inteiramente.

Comment: Muito obrigado.